# Cocoa one row table view or a horizontal list view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it posible to use table view to show just one row of a big amount of elements? What I'm looking for is for some kind of horizontal list, like we have in XCode preferences or Aperture image list.

It would behave just like a one columnt table view, but instead of showing the elements vertically, it should be horizontally.

Can you point me to where should I start from?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the desired UI?

Answer (score 6):

If you're okay with Leopard-only, The new NSCollectionView supports horizontal display.  Just set the collection view's number of rows to 1 in Interface Builder; it'll even handle the horizontal scroll bar for you.  The [IconCollection](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/IconCollection/index.html) sample code provides a simple demonstration of how it works.  It's bindings work similarly to a table view's, except instead of rows and columns, each object represented gets an 'item' (an object of type NSCollectionViewItem) that displays it, and those items will be laid out in a grid.  The sample code above demonstrates how to set up these 'items' in Interface Builder, which is definitely the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

With a table view? No. If I'm understanding correctly what you want, in the past I've created my own NSView subclass for this type of control. Define a data source protocol similar to NSTableView, and in your NSView drawRect method, draw the elements in order one by one from left to right. You can either keep track of paging in your control, or put it in a scroll view and resize yourself whenever the number of items changes.

Usually this type of thing starts off pretty simple, and gets a bit complex once you start handling caching, paging, selection, mouse and keyboard input and so on. My advice, start as simple as possible and add new features one by one, only after you've finished the previous task.